# How to load value from textbox into variable

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for way to load value from textbox into variable.

I've tried:

```
<p>
<textarea id="Text" name="Text" rows="6" cols="36"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" name="Button" value="Do it" onclick="javascript:job()" />
</p>
```

```
    function job() {

      var data = {};

      data = document.getElementById("Text").value;

      // other part of code
    }
```

This way doesnt work. If I put my data in {} script works perfectly

Working example:

```
var data = {
    "Something1": "Otherthing1",
    "Something2": "Otherthing2",
    "Something3": "Otherthing3",
};
```

But the data is each time different, thats why I need to load it from user input

Edit:
Well, working script from console returns data as

```
Object {Something1: "Otherthing1", Something2: "Otherthing2"}
```

Nothing else passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove the `javascript:` label. It is not needed
2. In case you want to PASTE JSON into the textfield, you need to use `JSON.parse`:

```js
function job() {
  var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("Text").value);
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <textarea id="Text" name="Text" rows="6" cols="36">{"1": "49.9138756N, 16.6112022E", "2": "50.0225236N, 15.7659417E"}</textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" name="Button" value="Do it" onclick="job()" />
</p>
```

---

First attempt to answer this with limited information:

Your code seems to work here: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/bodmshj4/

```js
function job() {
  var data = {};
  // example 1
  data["text"] = document.getElementById("Text").value;
  console.log("Example 1",data);
  // example 2
  data = document.getElementById("Text").value;
  console.log("Example 2",data);
  // example 3
  data = { 
   "text":document.getElementById("Text").value,
   "Something2": "Otherthing2",
   "Something3": "Otherthing3"
  }  
  console.log("Example 3",data);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <textarea id="Text" name="Text" rows="6" cols="36"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" name="Button" value="Do it" onclick="job()" />
</p>
```

but likely not how you expect.

```
var data = {}
```

assigns an empty object to data.

```
data = document.getElementById("Text").value;
```

overwrites the object with a string.

Perhaps one of these is what you want

```
var date = {} using 
data["text"] = document.getElementById("Text").value;
```

or

```
data["text"] = document.getElementById("Text").value;
```

would set a `data.text` value -

```
var data = { 
   "text":document.getElementById("Text").value
}
```

will also work for you.

Comment: Well, working script from console returns data as Object {Something1: "Otherthing1", Something2: "Otherthing2"} Nothing else passes. Tried yours code and it returns Object {text: ""Something1": "Otherthing1",↵    "Something2": "Otherthing2","}

Comment: Can you show me how you "tried my code" ? I am sure not like this: `var data = { 
       "text":document.getElementById("Text").value,
       "Something2": "Otherthing2",
       "Something3": "Otherthing3"
    }` - see updated example

Comment: Look, example here, this one is working correct - https://jsfiddle.net/72kgwL4u/  loadining it from textbox is different

Comment: So does this: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/1qLp8yx7/1/ - I removed the external script - it did not belong there, it is only used to display stuff here. I now see `Object {1: "49.9138756N, 16.6112022E", 2: "50.0225236N, 15.7659417E", 3: "asdaqd"}` if I type asdaqd into the field and click the button

Comment: If you need to PASTE `{"1": "49.9138756N, 16.6112022E", "2": "50.0225236N, 15.7659417E"}` into the textarea, see the update

Comment: thumbs up @mplungjan

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `data.text` instead of `data`

```js
function job() 
{
      var data = '';
      data = document.getElementById("Text").value;
   console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      // other part of code
}
```

```html
<p>
<textarea id="Text" name="Text" rows="6" cols="36"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" name="Button" value="Do it" onclick="javascript:job()" />
</p>
```

Comment: @mplungjan sorry  I didn't checked comments .. should I remove my answer ??

Comment: It's ok :) Nice console btw - I will borrow it :)

Comment: @JAdam  mark/accept  the best suitable answer that helped you to find solution of your problem .... Thank You.

Comment: now what actually you want ?? please explain what output do you want??

Comment: Exactly this output: https://jsfiddle.net/72kgwL4u/ But to textbox it comes like "1": "49.9138756N, 16.6112022E",  "2": "50.0225236N, 15.7659417E"

Comment: you want to push text area value into data object having two values before and third one after clicking the button ??

Comment: @J.Adam, look at the code I've changed , i put the value of text area in your existing data object,... now your data object has 3 values ..

Comment: Yeah I see, but when I remove data in {} yours data comes like Object {3: ""1": "49.9138756N, 16.6112022E",  "2": "50.0225236N, 15.7659417E""}. There wont be data in this script. everything needs to be loaded from textbox. Just need to find way to remove first 3: ""   and its done

Comment: it seems the problem with your textarea value... what is the content that you are entering into textarea...

Comment: i think you are entering `1: "49.9138756N, 16.6112022E", 2: "50.0225236N, 15.7659417E"` this thing in text area ,,,..

Comment: Yeah thats what I do. In script the variable is empty, it needs to be loaded from user input.

Comment: then simply put `{1: "49.9138756N, 16.6112022E", 2: "50.0225236N, 15.7659417E"}` this in your text area and click the button you wiill get your desired output.... test with mine code again...

Comment: That will only store the string, not create an object

Comment: `JSON.parse(data)` is the solution for that @mplungjan

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala Thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your object key/value pair by `object[key] = value` or `object.key = value`

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    var data = {};
    function job() {
          data["Something"+(++count)] =document.getElementById("Text").value;      
          console.log(data);
        }        
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use exactly an object you can mod your js function with this one:

```
var data = {}, index = 0;    
function job() {
   data['Something'+index] = document.getElementById("Text").value;
   index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok for you? https://jsfiddle.net/pLrjvk0x/

Even if you do the variable data an Object, value put it into a single string. I splitted it so you can have an Array. I understood you want the data into an Object instead a String and I could only imagine this way to to it (not an object but an Array). If this was not your problem tell me.

```
var splitted = data.split("\n");
```

Comment: Nope, it returns a lot of unwanted characters

Answer (score -2):

this may help you
var data = document.getElementById("Text").val();

Comment: .val() is jQuery. .value is plain JS